# MongoDb request find records by different fields

Tags: mongodb

is it possible to find records like this

i need to find all records where email was dublicated in another record by field named email_regisred

```
user.email.adderess==aaa@a.com
user.registred_email.address=aaa@a.com
i need to find ^^ these records
```

Comment: Can you add an example input and expected output?

Comment: it looks like :

Comment: first record have a filed email ==aaa@a.com

Comment: second record have a field email_registred==aaa@a.com

Comment: i need to find first and second records cuz it has same email

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6cgmsEceFSv)?

Comment: in sql in will be like this --select  u1,u2 from users u1,u2 where u1.email==u2.registred_email

Comment: J.F. there is one collection ,named users,users have fileds[List] named email and email_registred ,i need to find all records where user1.email==user2.registred email

Comment: So please, add and input example. Show us your collection.